# Accessing model associations in Rails 4 through a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, model-associations

I want to connect the User and Event models, so I created a Participation model. (One user can attend many events, and one event can have many users participating.)

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :statuses
  has_many :participations
  has_many :events, through: :participation

  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name

  def to_param
   profile_name
  end

  def full_name
    first_name + " " + last_name
  end
end
```

event.rb

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base


has_many :participations

has_many :users, through: :participations


end
```

participation.rb

```
class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :user

belongs_to :event

 end
```

I'm not sure how to link to this in my Events index; so far, I have a default link (`link_name`) in my `events/index.html.erb` that allows the page to load but just redirects to an individual event page when someone signs up:

`<%= link_to link_name, event %>`

I tried to change this part to this:

`<%= link_to New, new_participation_path(event) %>`

Which throws me this error:

```
NameError in Events#index
Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/events/index.html.erb where line #10 raised:

uninitialized constant ActionView::CompiledTemplates::New
Extracted source (around line #10):

     7  <%= event.event_date_time.strftime("%A %D at %I:%M %p") %></p>
     8 <div class="meta">
   9    <% link_name = "Sign up!" %>
 10    <%= link_to New, new_participation_path(event) %>
 11        <span class="admin">| <%= link_to "Edit", edit_event_path(event) %> |
 12      <% message = "Are you sure you want to delete this event?" %>
 13      <%= link_to "Delete", event, method: :delete, data: { confirm: message} %>
```

This is my create_participations migration:

class CreateParticipations < ActiveRecord::Migration

```
create_table :participations do |t|

    t.belongs_to :user, index: true

    t.belongs_to :event, index: true
    t.datetime :participation_date

    t.timestamps null: false

end

end
```

I added a new definition to my participation controller:

```
def new

    @participation = Participation.new

end
```

And here are my participation related routes (for some reason there are two sets):

```
    participation GET    /participation(.:format)         participation#index
   new_participation GET    /new_participation(.:format)     participation#new
  show_participation GET    /show_participation(.:format)    participation#show
         participate GET    /participate(.:format)           participation#create
update_participation GET    /update_participation(.:format)  participation#update
delete_participation GET    /delete_participation(.:format)  participation#destroy
 participation_index GET    /participation/index(.:format)   participation#index
  participation_show GET    /participation/show(.:format)    participation#show
participation_create GET    /participation/create(.:format)  participation#create
  participation_edit GET    /participation/edit(.:format)    participation#edit
participation_update GET    /participation/update(.:format)  participation#update
   participation_new GET    /participation/new(.:format)     participation#new
```

participation_destroy GET    /participation/destroy(.:format) participation#destroy

I'm not quite sure where i've gone wrong here.

Here is my entire github repo for this project:

https://github.com/yamilethmedina/wheels_registration.git